# RabbitMQ in Go: machinery worker cannot to connect to 0.0.0.0:5672 with message getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: go, rabbitmq, archlinux

RabbitMQ works fine in the wifi network in which I set up the RabbitMQ in a laptop running Arch Linux. However, when I use the same laptop in a different wifi network, I get the following error:

```
machinery: worker.go:42: Going to retry launching the worker. Error: Dial: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
machinery: retry.go:20: Retrying in x seconds
```

I have no clue as to why RabbitMQ works in one network and not in the other. I tried changing the url in the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` but there is no effect.

Here is the initial terminal output from RabbitMQ:
`

```
machinery: worker.go:27: Launching a worker with the following settings:
machinery: worker.go:28: - Broker: amqp://0.0.0.0:5672
machinery: worker.go:29: - ResultBackend: amqp://0.0.0.0:5672
machinery: worker.go:30: - Exchange: machinery_exchange
machinery: worker.go:31: - ExchangeType: direct
machinery: worker.go:32: - DefaultQueue: machinery_tasks
machinery: worker.go:33: - BindingKey: machinery_key
```

`

Answer (score -2):

First, I checked the status using:

```
sudo systemctl status rabbitmq
```

where, I got the message:

```
ERROR: epmd error for host "yourhostname": timeout (timed out establishing tcp connection)
```

Then, I addeded the following entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1    yourhostname.localgroup    yourhostname
```

Then, I restarted rabbitmq using:

```
sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq
```

I did not change any configuration in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`